# I would like to find out why my Login works on 000Webhost but does not work when I try on my system

Tags: php, mysql, validation, authentication, session

When I signup successfully via the localhost file, it sends to the database successfully and echos success. But when I try using the same details to log in, it returns an error.

However, this is not the same via the hosted site. It works perfectly on 000webhost.

My login code:

```
 <?php

if (isset($_POST['login-submit'])) {
    require 'dbh.inc.php';

    $mailusername = $_POST['useremail'];
    $password = $_POST['userpwd'];

    if (empty($mailusername)  || empty($password)) {
        header("Location: ../login.php?error=emptyfields");
        exit();
    }
    else{

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username=? OR email=?";

        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            header("Location: ../login.php?error=sqlError");
            exit();
        }
        else{

            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $mailusername, $mailusername);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $pwdCheck = password_verify($password, $row['password']);

                if ($pwdCheck == false) {
                    header("Location: ../login.php?error=wrongPwd");
                    exit();
                }
                else if($pwdCheck == true){
                    session_start();

                    $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['id'];
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];

                    header("Location: ../index.php?login=success");
                    exit();

                }
                else{
                    header("Location: ../login.php?error=wrongPass");
                    exit();
                }
            }
            else{
                header("Location: ../login.php?error=noUser");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }

}
else{
    header("Location: ../login.php");
    exit();
}
```

My signup code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    require 'dbh.inc.php';

    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $passwordRepeat = $_POST['confirm_password'];

//if empty input
    if (empty($fullname) || empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($passwordRepeat)) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=emptyfields&fullname="); //. $fullname."&username=". $username."&email".$email);
        exit();
    }
    else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username) ){
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidemail&username=");
        exit();
    }
    //if email is invalid return error
    elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidemail&fullname=");
        exit();
    }
    //checking for valid password
    elseif(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)){
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidusername&email=");
        exit();
    }
    //check confirmed password
    else if($password !== $passwordRepeat){
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=passwordRepeat&username=");
        exit();
    }
    //if username is already taken
    else{

        $sql = "SELECT username FROM `users` WHERE username=?";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
            exit();
        }
        else{
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

            //did we get a match?

            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
            if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                header("Location: ../signup.php?error=usernametaken");// .$username);
                exit();
            }
            else{
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `users`(`fullname`, `username`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
                    exit();
                }
                else{
                    $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $fullname, $username, $email, $hashedPwd);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                    header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
else{
    header("Location: ../signup.php");
    exit();
}
```

I need help, please. As I need to integrate a dashboard but can't seem to get logged in the first place.

Comment: *"it returns an error."* what error ?

Comment: @Cid thanks.  It returns that the password is incorrect

Comment: @Cid this exactly: 

"Location: ../login.php?error=wrongPwd"

Comment: How large is the column where you save the passwords? Is it 60 or more characters?

Comment: @JayBlanchard 50 presently.

Comment: @Cid a *silent* one ;-)

Comment: Note that `if ($pwdCheck == false) { /* wrong password */ } else if ($pwdCheck == true) { /* good password */ } else { /* wrong password again */ }` can be simplified to `if (!$pwdCheck) { /* wrong password */ } else { /* good password */ }`

Comment: @Cid thanks. Would be improved upon.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thanks again and your advice is duly noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column holding the password hashes created by `password_hash()` must be at least 60 characters in order to work properly. Please adjust the size of the column holding the hash, then reregister the users. Once done, the passwords will verify properly.

From the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php):

> PASSWORD_DEFAULT - Use the bcrypt algorithm (default as of PHP 5.5.0). Note that this constant is designed to change over time as new and stronger algorithms are added to PHP. For that reason, the length of the result from using this identifier can change over time. **Therefore, it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice).**

Comment: I had a feeling about that earlier myself.